# Should I be asking for general advice on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I want to ask for on the Game Development section of Stack Overflow. It has absolutely nothing to do with any actual code or work.

Is this allowed?

Comment: It will almost certainly get flagged as too broad.  It's not really the forum for such a discussion.  There are plenty of other places that are :)

Comment: It really helps us answer if you give some *examples* of the type(s) of question(s) you want to ask. Asking vaguely, there is little we can do but regurgitate the advice already in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There is a [gamedev.se] stack exchange, but even there a "general advice" question would probably be closed as too broad or opinion-based.

Comment: Perhaps [Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or [Arqade Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. We'd need to know more about the question, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not a place for "general advice".

You need to have a specific problem that you can ask a question about. It doesn't *have* to include source code (although most good questions do)—we allow questions concerning conceptual problems in software development, as long as they have a narrowly-defined scope and can be reasonably answered.

What we do not allow are discussion-based questions where there is no real answer and everyone has only to share their opinion. Or where the question is so broad that it would be impossible to post a single authoritative answer.